# Node.js/Express not outputting console.log, highcharts.js giving undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, highcharts, express-generator

I'm from a PHP background but trying out a Node/Express site for the first time.  I've successfully used express-generator to get the basic skeleton running on localhost.  I've also installed highcharts via npm and followed the [instructions given by highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm) to add it into my project via require(). I now have this in my index.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
var router = express.Router();

// Load module after Highcharts is loaded
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);

console.log(Highcharts);

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', { /*Highcharts options*/ });

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have two questions:

1) console.log() is not outputting to terminal or browser console when running DEBUG=project:* npm start.  Is it outputting to something else I haven't checked or do I need to do something more to see this?

2) require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts); is throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs//node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js:9:115
Where did I mess up?

Comment: Highcharts is a client side framework, you don't load it on your server.  You will need access to the highcharts object on the front-end.  See this link: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation.  The npm code you are referring to is if you are using something like requirejs on the frontend.

Comment: `highcharts/modules/exporting` is [browser-only code](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview), not a Node module. You don't get a console log because your script errors out before it reaches that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the Highcharts example you linked to is using `require()` is that many people run their browser code through [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), in order to keep using their favorite Node idioms and maintain some level of [isomorphic design](http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/).

Despite that, Highcharts is still meant for the browser and cannot be used in Node. Your Express app is supposed to deliver an HTML page which itself loads Highcharts by some means. You aren't restricted to using Browserify, but it is a popular choice for this use case.

Also, as for your uncertainty about where to look for logs: always the terminal. Your Node programs will *never* log to the browser console, unless you go out of your way to make them do so using fancy things like [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).

Comment: Excellent detailed answer, thanks.  Things are beginning to make a bit more sense to me now.  As for the console.log problem, I'm not sure why, but it has started working now.  I can only assume I messed up with the order of file saving/running debug or had the app crashing out other times before console.log() was reached - frankly I don't know.  Thanks a bunch regardless!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I suspect you are right about why it wasn't working before. One way to make Node be more noisy about errors is to add this little string to the top of every file: `'use strict';` see: http://justbuildsomething.com/node-js-best-practices/#4

Answer (score 0):

Take a a look at the error:

> require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts); is throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Its looking for the `document` which is a browser API, HighCharts is client side only.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.  I guess I'm still a bit baffled by the idea of server-side JS vs. client-side and how these things are separated in a node/express app.